# Exclude items with JPQL "not in"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I want to exclude Items tagged with certain tags with the following JPQL query:

```
select distinct i from Item i join i.tags t where t not in (:excludedTags)
```

It works if an `item` has only a single `tag` and this `tag` is in the `excludedTags` list. But if there is any other `tag` on that `item`, it gets still selected!

The relevant part of the model:

```
@Entity
class Tag {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
  var items
}

@Entity
class Item {
  @ManyToMany
  var tags
}
```

How can I exclude items that have any excluded tag with JPQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be something like this instead:

```
select distinct i from Item i where not exists (
    select t from Item i2 
    join i2.tags tag
    where i2.id = i.id
    and tag.id in :excludedTags)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as a slight variant: `... not exists (select tag from Item i2 join i2.tags tag where i2.id = i.id and tag in (:excludedTags))`. As far as I know the parenthesis around `excludedTags` are needed due to a hibernate bug.

Comment: That bug has ben fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: I'm using 4.1.9, not that old.